# Recover the contents of a formatted disk?

Tags: partition, btrfs, gparted

I've been setting up a new system, and recovering backups from my formatted external hard drive. I was able to get *most* of what I needed from it, but the btrfs partition was somehow reformatted as swap. In an attempt to fix the issue, I reformatted it again as btrfs (using gparted), but this did not recover any of the old data. As I have not written to the drive (beyond the format changes), *I assume all of the information is still there*, but inaccessible.

- Is there a way I can recover this data? In other words, is there a way to "latch on" to the old metadata (and root) of the original btrfs partition?
- What could have caused the partition to be reformatted to swap in the first place?

Note: this whole situation could have been due to error on my own part, as I was trying to fix some swap issues. However, I was unable to find the command that would have formatted the partition as swap (`mkswap /dev/sdb1`) in my bash history.

Answer (score 1):

Testdisk is what I would use.

[Link to Testdisk download](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download)

Not a btrfs user,and I don't suppose it's likely, but perhaps there was some kind of automatic partitioning as there is in many linux systems that you maybe forgot to change?

Nevertheless testdisk usually does the job for me.

Comment: I tried using Testdisk. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I was able to get my backups since October from my old laptop drive, and that is good enough. I'll be more careful in the future.